# Python - Sensor Data includes unwanted symbols - how to achieve a clean dataset?

Tags: python, split

I am reading a .txt file with sensory data. This data I want to split at each "," and delete needless symbols like \x00.  (By the way, is it a tab?

Spliting the data...

```
with open(inc_file, "r") as f_inc:
    for line in f_inc:
        for z, line in enumerate(f_inc):
            clean_line = line.strip().split(",")
            content_inc.append(clean_line)
```

The list looks like:

```
[['51\x00\x00', '24\x00\x00', '236\x00', '52\x00', '904\x009\x00\x00', '254\x00', '56\x00', 
'52\x00', '6778\x00\x00\x00', '11:46:19:255', '181219\x00'], ['51\x00\x00', '24\x00\x00', 
'236\x00', '52\x00', '904\x009\x00\x00', '254\x00', '56\x00', '52\x00', '6778\x00\x00\x00', 
'11:46:19:255', '181219\x00']]
```

How can i achieve a clean result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to remove the `\x00` characters (those a null bytes), you can use `.replace()`. Change line 4 it like this:

```
clean_line = line.strip().replace('\x00', '').split(",")
```